# Why is the \item not directly under the frame title, but on another page?

Tags: vertical-alignment

[image]Here is the code used in the picture below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{berlin}
\title{Tracking im Internet} \author{Petros Kladis} \date{06.Juni.2020}
\begin{document}
    \frame{ \maketitle }
    \frame{\frametitle{Gliederung} \tableofcontents }
        \section{Einleitung}
        \section{Cookies}
        \section{Was passiert mit unsere Data}
        \section{Wie kann ich es vermeiden}
            \frame{\frametitle{Warum habe ich das Thema ausgewählt?}}
                \begin{itemize}
                \item Big Data 
                \item Wie wird man getracked 
                \item Was kann damit machen 
                \item Online Sichercheit 
                \end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! This is because you are using `\frame` wrongly, the closing `}` needs to go at the end of the contents of that frame. However, I'd use `\begin{frame}\frametitle{...}<contents>\end{frame}` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\frame` incorrectly, it should have the closing `}` at the end of the contents of the frame. However, I'd use the `frame` environment, where this is easier to see.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{Berlin}
\title{Tracking im Internet} 
\author{Petros Kladis} 
\date{06.~Juni~2020}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Gliederung} 
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Einleitung}
\section{Cookies}
\section{Was passiert mit unsere Data}
\section{Wie kann ich es vermeiden}


\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Warum habe ich das Thema ausgew\"ahlt?}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Big Data 
    \item Wie wird man getracked 
    \item Was kann damit machen 
    \item Online Sichercheit 
    \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]